# Implementing case-insensitive passwords with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic, case-insensitive

I use Authlogic in my app and I want to make things more convenient for my users by ignoring capitalization when I check their passwords (similar to what [facebook does](http://www.labnol.org/internet/facebook-account-passwords/21241/))

What's the best way to implement this?

Also, how can I transition existing users to case-insensitive passwords? I.e., I assume I have to resave what is now `crypt(password)` as `crypt(password.downcase)`?

Comment: I don't understand why people ever want to do this.  it makes brute forcing weak passwords thousands of times easier.  The minimum threshold of a "secure" password goes from about 8 characters to about 13.

Comment: You sir are the voice of reason. I wish more people would understand that just because facebook does it it doesn't mean it's a good idea in the first place. Blizzard does it as well.

Comment: facebook does this?  brb checking

Comment: Facebook doesn't do this.  You scared me there for a minute.

Comment: DOES it make brute forcing weak passwords materially easier? Unless you force users to use a combination of characters (which is SUPER annoying IMO), everyone's password will be all lowercase (or all uppercase, depending on whether caps lock is on)

Comment: FYI Facebook used to do this - back 2012, not anymore